# Send lat lng from variable to google maps

Tags: html, json, api, maps

I´m trying to make a simple code using Google maps API (I'm new at this), the idea is to get the latitude and longitude from JSON variable direccion to the var uluru.
I have the following code:
Where am I wrong?

Thanks in advance.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>


      function initMap() {


      var direccion=[
        {
          lugar:'CICESE',
          lat:31.8675375,
          lng: -116.6686867
        },
        {
          lugar: 'Casa',
          lat:31.8915163,
          lng:-116.6879557
        }
      ];


        var uluru = {lat: direccion.lat, lng: direccion.lng};//{lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgMyVeh8DwebGfZHjiNjyle4xFe9pKSdc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please review [Ask] and edit your post to include information about what you expect to happen and exactly what is happening.  Is it failing?  What error codes are you getting?

Comment: Ok, i already change my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your direction is json array, you need to access by index as below:

```
var uluru = {lat: direccion[0].lat, lng: direccion[0].lng};
```

see my example below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
       #map {
        height: 400px;
        width: 100%;
       }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h3>My Google Maps Demo</h3>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>


      function initMap() {


      var direccion=[
        {
          lugar:'CICESE',
          lat:31.8675375,
          lng: -116.6686867
        },
        {
          lugar: 'Casa',
          lat:31.8915163,
          lng:-116.6879557
        }
      ];


        var uluru = {lat: direccion[0].lat, lng: direccion[0].lng};//{lat: -25.363, lng: 131.044};
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          zoom: 4,
          center: uluru
        });
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: uluru,
          map: map
        });
      }
    </script>
    <script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDgMyVeh8DwebGfZHjiNjyle4xFe9pKSdc&callback=initMap">
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well thank you so much, i didn't notice that. <3 thanks!